# Корректность словосочетания "уважаемые друзья"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистическая-сочетаемость

На мой взгляд, "уважаемые друзья" звучит столь же нелепо, как, скажем, "уважаемая жена"; ведь дружба — отношения более высокого уровня, чем просто уважение. Я даже написал однажды об этом ведущему одной радиопередачи — и он убрал это словосочетание из своего лексикона. Тем не менее, я обнаружил в Нацкорпусе несколько десятков документов с этим словосочетанием. Помогите разобраться.

Дополнение.

Я больше склонен думать не о том, с каким эпитетом обращаться к "друзьям", которые на самом деле вам не друзья, а о том, чтобы использовать обращение "друзья" более избирательно. Кстати, тот самый радиоведущий после моего письма оставил слово "уважаемые", но заменил слово "друзья" каким-то другим. Но если уж вы решили "повысить регистр" и назвать собравшихся (телезрителей, радиослушателей) друзьями (а я именно так это вижу — как гиперболу, "повышение регистра"), то, как мне кажется, вам не следует вносить диссонанс, признаваясь тем, кого вы назвали друзьями, всего-лишь в уважении.

Answer (score 3):

При всей сомнительности такого сочетания вне контекста, можно порассуждать о формах, оттенках и условностях "дружбы". В *личной дружбе*, когда обе стороны считают себя друзьями, такое обращение практически всегда *неуместно*. Возможны лишь редкие ситуации, когда некто ведёт себя как новый друг, а другая сторона относится к этому по принципу "уважаю, но сам дружить не буду" (не могу в равной мере быть другом по соображениям материального или возрастного неравенства, неверия в искренность предложенной дружбы - мало ли, может, в спонсоры набиваются и т. п.). Видимо, такие ситуации возможны и в дипломатии (в беседе недавних соперников, решивших забыть старые обиды - вспомним отношения с Турцией), в приветственной речи на бизнес-встрече высокопоставленных лиц,  когда устойчивое выражение "дорогие друзья" выглядит неестественным. В телепередаче же всегда подразумевается *условное* наименование "**друзья передачи**" (постоянные зрители, которых в лицо не знают, - тоже ситуация "неравенства"), поэтому уход от *штампа* "дорогие друзья" (нет сердечных чувств к каждому, делающих друзей "дорогими") выглядит допустимым: "уважение" к зрителю в этой ситуации буквально - для него стараются.

Answer (score 1):

Друг ― многозначное слово. Словосочетания "уважаемые друзья", дорогие друзья" не относятся к первому  значению слова, **это условное обращение к аудитории**, выражение чувства симпатии  к собравшимся людям.

**ДРУГ,**  1. Человек, связанный с кем-л. **отношениями дружбы.** 2. кого-чего. **Сторонник, приверженец, защитник.** Д. обиженных и угнетённых. Д. детей. Д. природы. Д. свободы, истины (книжн.). 3. **Дружеское обращение** (обычно к близкому или знакомому человеку). Д. мой, передай мне книгу. Как ваша диссертация, мой д.? О чём задумался, д.? // **Разг**. **В обращении к чужому, незнакомому человеку**. Куда ты торопишься, д.?

Примеры:

Уважаемый господин Президент! **Уважаемые друзья**! Позвольте мне еще раз сердечно приветствовать вас в Кремле. [В. В. Путин. Выступление на российско-вьетнамских переговорах в расширенном составе (2004) // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004.06.29]

Здравствуйте, **уважаемые друзья** ― сотрудники редакции газеты «Биология»!
[ 2003.01.01]

**Друзья мои, милые, дорогие друзья мои!** Покидая этот дом навсегда… [А. П. Чехов. Вишневый сад (1904)]

Cлово ректора: **Дорогие друзья!** Этот год для Физтеха ― особенный. [Николай Кудрявцев. Cлово ректора // «За науку», 2014]

Comment: О приведенных примерах. Именно недавнее обращение первого лица и поставило меня в тупик. Но не убедило. А у ректора друзья дорогие!

Comment: Мне кажется, мы должны говорить не о первом, не о втором, а о третьем пункте: "дружеское обращение (обычно к близкому или знакомому человеку)". Не условное, а именно дружеское. Не уважаемый друг природы, а просто друг, то есть якобы ваш друг. Уж если вы условно говорите мне друг, извольте условно говорить также, что я вам дорог. Не знаю уж, как и аргументировать. Ну например, вы условно называете ученика гением и говорите "наш умный гений". Каково?

Comment: Мне кажется, что всё намного проще: это принятый этикет, условность. Вот еще вариант: Уважаемые участники и гости конференции! Дамы и господа!  Но надо, наверное,  знать, кто для нас  друзья, а кто дамы и господа.